# Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol 'WCSessionDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity, watchos-3

Since upgrading on Xcode 8 (Beta 1) and Swift 3 I have an error in this line:

```
class CloudViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {
```

It says :

> Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'WCSessionDelegate'

This is my (with Xcode 7 and Swift 2 working) code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(WCSession.isSupported()){
        self.session = WCSession.default()
        self.session.delegate = self
        self.session.activate()
    }
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {

    print("didReceiveMessage")

    watchMessageHandler.getMessage(message)

}
```

This error also shows up in the WKInterfaceController classes.

Comment: did you build/ clean project?

Comment: @AkshanshThakur yes, multiple times

Comment: If you read the full error in the build output, it tells you how you're not conforming to the protocol

Comment: I think you are forgetting to implement the methods that are required for the protocol conformation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every protocol comes with a set of methods that you are supposed to implement in order to conform to them. You must write those methods in your class to conform to it.

For example, in a UIViewController, if you decide to have a tableView, you must add the `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, like so:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

}
```

But, this is not complete implementation of the protocol. This is mere declaration.

To actually have your View Controller conform to the protocol, you will have to implement two methods, namely: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and`numberOfRowsInSection`. This is the requirement of the protocol.

So, the complete implementation would look something like:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExperienceCell

         return cell
     }

     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
     }

}
```

Therefore, you must look into the documentation and find what methods does your protocol require the class to implement.
That should solve this problem. And I don't think it is to do anything with Xcode 8 or swift 3

**EDIT**   Here: This is what [apple documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSessionDelegate_protocol/)

> Most methods of this protocol are optional. You implement the methods you need to respond to the data transfer operations that your apps support. However, apps should implement support for the session:activationDidCompleteWithState:error: method to support asynchronous activation, and the delegate in your iPhone app should implement the sessionDidBecomeInactive: and sessionDidDeactivate: methods to support multiple Apple Watches.

Answer (score 16):

With Swift 3, you should implement this methods according to the new protocol

> session:activationDidCompleteWithState:error:
>
> sessionDidBecomeInactive:
>
> sessionDidDeactivate:

because they are not marked as optional on protocol anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Add this Methods in your CloudViewController

```
internal func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: NSError?){
}
```

This error suggest you need to implement the required protocol method for WCSessionDelegate